# How to run threads in tauri?

Tags: javascript, rust, tauri

I have a tauri application for syncing files that land in a directory. The UI prompts the user to select a directory, select an extension type and a bucket name from a dropdown.

Files containing the selected extension will be uploaded to s3, and other files will be omitted.

The solidjs code which calls the tauri registered method "sync_directory" is below:

```
async function createDirectorySync() {
    let result = await invoke("sync_directory", { directory: directory(), filter: filter(), bucket: bucket() });

    console.log(result);
  }
```

This method is simply invoked when clicking on a button like:

```
<button type="button" class="sync-btn" onClick={() => createDirectorySync()}>Sync</button>
```

The rust code corresponding to this method does a few things serially:

- Starts watching the directory for created files
- Makes an API call to get the bucket name from aws dynamo DB
- Uploads the file to s3 at the destination bucket

Here's the code:

```
#[tauri::command]
fn sync_directory(directory: &str, filter: &str, bucket: char) -> SyncStatus {
    let (sender, receiver) = channel();

    // Create a watcher object, delivering debounced events.
    // The notification back-end is selected based on the platform.
    let mut watcher = watcher(sender, Duration::from_secs(1)).unwrap();

    // Add a path to be watched. All files and directories at that path and
    // below will be monitored for changes.
    let target_path = &directory.to_string();
    println!("Watching {}", Path::new(target_path).display());
    let target_dir_exists = Path::new(target_path).exists();
    if !target_dir_exists {
        let sync_status: SyncStatus = SyncStatus {
            directory: "".to_string(),
            filter: "".to_string(),
            status: false,
        };
        return sync_status;
    }
    let _watcher_result = watcher.watch(target_path, RecursiveMode::Recursive);
    // If the user supplies only a path then we'll display all
    // files which are altered, but won't tail any file.
    process_directory(receiver, filter, bucket);

    let sync_status: SyncStatus = SyncStatus {
        directory: directory.to_string(),
        filter: filter.to_string(),
        status: true,
    };
    sync_status
}
```

```
fn process_directory(receiver: Receiver<DebouncedEvent>, filter: &str, bucket: char) {
    loop {
        //println!("{}", receiver.recv().unwrap());
        match receiver.recv() {
            Ok(event) => {
                let current_time = chrono::offset::Local::now().format("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S");
                match event {
                    notify::DebouncedEvent::Write(file_path) => {
                        println!(
                            "{} Write: {}",
                            current_time,
                            file_path.as_path().display().to_string()
                        )
                    }
                    notify::DebouncedEvent::Chmod(file_path) => {
                        println!(
                            "{} Chmod: {}",
                            current_time,
                            file_path.as_path().display().to_string()
                        )
                    }
                    notify::DebouncedEvent::Remove(file_path) => {
                        println!(
                            "{} Remove: {}",
                            current_time,
                            file_path.as_path().display().to_string()
                        )
                    }
                    notify::DebouncedEvent::Rename(file_path, _) => {
                        println!(
                            "{} Rename: {}",
                            current_time,
                            file_path.as_path().display().to_string()
                        )
                    }
                    notify::DebouncedEvent::Error(err, Some(file_path)) => {
                        println!(
                            "{} Error: {}, {}",
                            current_time,
                            err,
                            file_path.as_path().display().to_string()
                        )
                    }
                    notify::DebouncedEvent::Create(file_path) => {
                        let file_properties = get_file_properties(file_path);
                        println!("{} Create: {}", current_time, file_properties.name);

                        if file_properties.ext == filter
                            && bucket as u32 >= 65
                            && bucket as u32 <= 90
                        {
                            let key =
                                format!("{}_{}", get_current_timestamp(), file_properties.name);

                            println!("Inside if");

                            let rt = tokio::runtime::Builder::new_current_thread()
                                .enable_all()
                                .build()
                                .unwrap();

                            let _res = rt.block_on(async {
                                upload_to_s3(file_properties.path, key.to_string(), station).await
                            });
                        }
                    }
                    _other => {}
                }
            }
            Err(e) => println!("watch error: {:?}", e),
        }
    }
}
```

The upload part of the code:

```
async fn upload_to_s3(file_name: String, key: String, bucket_ref: char) -> Result<(), Error> {
   ...
   query_s3_bucket_for_station invoked from here
   upload_object is also invoked from here
}

async fn query_s3_bucket_for_station(
    client: &DynamodbClient,
    key: &char,
) -> Result<
    std::option::Option<Vec<HashMap<std::string::String, AttributeValue>>>,
    SdkError<aws_sdk_dynamodb::error::QueryError>,
> {
    ...
}

async fn upload_object(
    client: &Client,
    bucket_name: &str,
    file_name: &str,
    key: &str,
) -> Result<(), Error> {
    println!("Uploading file: {}", file_name);

    let body = ByteStream::from_path(Path::new(file_name)).await;
    client
        .put_object()
        .bucket(bucket_name)
        .key(key)
        .body(body.unwrap())
        .send()
        .await?;

    Ok(())
}
```

My UI freezes as soon as the watcher is created to watch the directory.
[image]

My guess is that I need to do some sort of threaded operation here. Any help is highly appreciated!

Comment: Don't `await` the result of `invoke` in your JS code. Instead use `then` to run code when the task finishes. E.g. `invoke (…).then (function () { console.log (…); })`

Comment: Make the tauri command async (either by actually making it an `async fn` or by annotating it with `#[tauri::command(async)]`). non-async commands will run on the main thread and therefore block the UI.

Comment: @Jmb  Using `.then` didn't work because the UI freezes due to some blocking in the rust code. 
@FabianLars `[tauri::command(async)]` didn't work either. The upload doesn't go through now after these changes.
I believe it has something to do with the `rt.block_on` which blocks the main thread from executing.

Comment: i guess it would solve your problem by making both `sync_directory` and `process_directory` be `async fn`, since by doing so you can remove `block_on` and keep all things nonblocking.